# Calling phone sms api by use of phonegap using javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova

I am new in phonegap .I have  two text field which contains mobile n. and another text field contains some message as per user input.And one button for sending sms .
I am using below code.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var ComposeSMS = function(){

    var contactno = document.test.phonenumber.value;
    var messagetext=document.test.message.value;

    window.location.href = "sms:contactno?body=messagetext";

    } 

<form name="test">
<input type="text" name="phonenumber"  /></br>
<input type="text" name="message"/></br>
<input onclick="ComposeSMS();" type="button" value="Compose SMS text with number and body" />
</form>
```

My problem is i am not getting contact n. and messages in mobile sms body please any one have idea then please reply asap.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
 window.location.href = "sms:"+contactno+"?body="+messagetext;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a phone number, but apparently not a default text for your message. 
http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#SMS

Why not you used iOS 4 Feature called MessageViewController, You can used Message/SMS plugin for phonegap-

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/SMSComposer

Comment: Dear sir,As for your suggestion if i will use messageviewcontroller feauture in my app.Then it will work only in ios phone and i want to make app for all platform android,iphone,blackberry.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
window.location = "sms:contactno?body=messagetext";
```

instead.