# Send SMS using phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Send SMS through PhoneGap on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193997/send-sms-through-phonegap-on-android)

I have a hybrid application for Android and iPhone using html5, javascript, jquery and phonegap. I want to implement send message on this application. Please help me, how I implement this.

Please provide me the steps.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254887/calling-phone-sms-api-by-use-of-phonegap-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

**you should try this.** this is phonegap plugin

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/SMSPlugin

Comment: I want to perform sms for both Android as well as Android. How I do this.

Comment: use this this are all plugin download this and have fun https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins